# TypeError: modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra'

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to use the modelformset_factory to render multiple forms. However, when trying to run the server, this error occurs `TypeError: modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra'`

All the online sources say that I should be able to specify the `extra` argument in the modelform_factory but I can't seem to.

forms.py

```py
class MapSeniorTeachForm(ModelForm):
    role = forms.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __init__(self, teach_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MapSeniorTeachForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.teach_id = teach_id
        self.fields['senior'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)])
    
    class Meta:
        model = MapSeniorTeach
        fields = ['role', 'senior']

MapSeniorTeachFormset = modelform_factory(MapSeniorTeach, form=MapSeniorTeachForm, extra=1)
```

Clipped Output Log

```
File "C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Documents\VSCodeProjects\bansheeApp\bansheeApp_project\banshee\training\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Documents\VSCodeProjects\bansheeApp\bansheeApp_project\banshee\training\views.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .forms import LessonTeachForm, ActivityTeachForm, MapSeniorTeachFormset
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Documents\VSCodeProjects\bansheeApp\bansheeApp_project\banshee\training\forms.py", line 25, in <module>
    MapSeniorTeachFormset = modelform_factory(MapSeniorTeach, form=MapSeniorTeachForm, extra=1)
```

One thing to note, if I remove the extra keyword, one instance of the form is successfully rendered.

Here are some sources I was speaking about before:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/
https://micropyramid.com/blog/understanding-djangos-model-formsets-in-detail-and-their-advanced-usage/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're using `modelform_factory` but you should be using `modelformset_factory`

Comment: ohh thank you thank you, if you make that a standalone answer to the question, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Iain Shelvington said in the comments:

I miswrote `modelform_factory` instead of the correct `modelformset_factory`